# start and stop OS X router daemon

Tags: launchd

I'd like to be able to stop and (re)start the OS X routing daemon and review the routed configuration file(s).  I think this would involve using launchctl unload and load, but I don't know the name of the routing plist file... Any hints on how to track this down?

Comment: OS X doesn't run -- or even contain the binary for -- `routed`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I posted a related question and got this response:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147482/where-does-the-os-x-routing-table-come-from

Answer (score 1):

There is no OS X daemon for routed.

Comment: OK, thanks... So what happens at system startup to configure the routing table?

Comment: I can't find an answer to that @RicSteinberger. It's strange that the manpage for the route utility refers to a non-existent system daemon.

Comment: I do know that the routed daemon used to exist in older Mac OS X Server versions, it used to be in /etc/routed.

Comment: I believe that DHCP configures the routing table now.